# ddlInstance object reference not set error in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Below is my code

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As     EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dt As DataTable = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ddlInstances.Items.Add(String.Concat(dr("ServerName"), "\\", dr("InstanceName")))
    Next
End Sub
```

I have imports statements as

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

when trying to add references, Im not able to find anything related to Sql.
is that the cause of the error that ddlinstance is not recognized? Do I need to install SQL server Express edition installed in my developer machine?
Please help

Comment: Where have you declared `ddlInstances`? Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: I'm guessing that ddlInstances was declared something like `Dim ddlIntstances As List(Of someobject)` - My most common mistake - Try `Dim ddlInstances As New List(Of someobject)`

Comment: `ddlInstances` appears to be a control of some sort? what is it and where is it declared?

Comment: Im trying to populate server instances which are in local machine as well any remote server connected to same domain to the DropDown box.

Comment: As per @Plutonix's question - could you paste the markup with ddlInstances?

Comment: I have used me.combobox1.items.add and issue resolved.. Thank you all